# Deploying a web app using Vite, I am unable to deploy the .js file. "<script src="/index.js"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module"

Tags: javascript, deployment, web-applications, production, vite

When Deploying a web app using **Vite**, I am unable to deploy the .js file. Getting the below issue.

```
$ vite build
vite v2.8.6 building for production...
**\<script src="/index.js"\> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute**
transforming...
```

I cannot use in script **`type=module`** as I have no import of code to be done. If I use then error is coming.

If anyone can help.

I tried using script `type=module` but error is coming. Is there any way I can deploy with **Vite** without using **`type=module`** ?

Comment: Could you provide some more information with what kind of errors you get when using `type="module"`? Generally, errors that that attribute causes should not be too hard to fix.

Comment: I have this problem too. I'm trying to include some old, pre-module JS libraries on the page that assume they'll be included using a ["classic script"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attribute_is_not_set_default_an_empty_string_or_a_javascript_mime_type) (expect a global `this` to equal `window`, expect top level `var` declarations to be global properties on `window`, etc).

I don't want to edit to those libraries to make them work with `type="module"`, they do their job just fine when included via a classic `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the public directory](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory).

you can copy your `index.js` file there